# Print all cominations of numbers in ascending order recursively (with length n between 1 and 9)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I want to print all number combinations that are in ascending order. The output should go like: 012, 013, 014, ..., 789 for n = 3. I tried to solve it using recursion, however I'm having the StackOverflowError. So it means it never reaches the result. Here is my code so far:

````
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    print_combinations(a, 0, 3);
  }

  static void print_combinations(int[] a, int index, int n) {
    if (n > 0 && n < 10) {
      if (index == n - 1) {
        if (is_ascending(a, n)) {
          System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a));
          System.out.print(", ");
        }
        if (!has_ended(a, n)) {
          print_combinations(a, 0, n);
        }
      } else {
        while (a[index] <= 9 - n + index - 1) {
          print_combinations(a, index + 1, n);
          if (index < n - 1 && a[index] == 9 - n + index - 1) {
            a[index + 1] = 0;
          }
          a[index]++;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static boolean has_ended(int[] a, int n) {
    int ctr = 0;
    while (ctr < n) {
      if (a[ctr] != 10 - n + ctr) {
        return false;
      } else {
        ctr++;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  static boolean is_ascending(int[] a, int n) {
    int ctr = 0;

    while (ctr < n - 1) {
      if (a[ctr] >= a[ctr + 1]) {
        return false;
      }
      ctr++;
    }
    return true;
  }
}```
````

Comment: You can check this alghoritms, : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

I'm not sure if this is what you looking for.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Turing85 I know how to debug, I just can't seem to understand how to increment multiple nested loops correctly that get created through recursion

Comment: I do not understand your comment. The program provided does not use nested loops. There is no such thing as "*multiple nestend loops [...] that get created through recursion*".

Comment: @Turing85 if you call print_combinations it will create a while loop which creates another while loop with every iteration which creates another one until the index reaches n - 1. Have you even looked at the code?

Comment: 'Nested' is understood by most programmers as a static structure of the written program text.  Recursive activation does not change that.

Comment: @ErnestPW I have looked at the code. And again: There is no such thing as "*multiple nestend loops [...] that get created through recursion*". The visibility and accessibility of block-scoped variables does not change, regardless of whether recursion is used. If we debug the program and inspect the call stack, we can see the different stack frames, containing the different stack variables in different recursion depths.

Comment: @accessviolation but wouldn't it become a nested structure if i made 9 while loops instead of a recursive solution? that's what i'm trying to get to, i can make it work by writing out all the loops instead of recursion, but don't really know what i'm missing compared to a solution with many while/for loops

Comment: This looks very suspicious: `if (!has_ended(a, n)) {print_combinations(a, 0, n);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are these issues in your code:

- The base case is not when `if (index == n - 1)`, because then you still need to populate `a[index]` will different digits. The base case is when `if (index == n)`.
- Once the base case is treated, you should *not* make even deeper recursive calls, as you do with the `if (!has_ended(a, n))` block. No, the principle of recursion is that you *backtrack* once you have reached the end of a search path, so you simply need to return. The caller will deal with other variations. This `if` block should be removed.
- The `while` loop ends too soon. Its condition should not be `a[index] <= 9 - n + index - 1`, but `a[index] <= 9 - n + index + 1`.
- The `if` condition inside that loop is testing the wrong array value, and comparing with the wrong limit. It should not be `a[index] == 9 - n + index - 1`, but `a[index + 1] == 9 - n + index + 3`.
- With `Arrays.toString(a)` you'll get all 10 entries of `a` instead of the first `n` of them. You could do `Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, n))`.

With those fixes your code will work:

```
  static void print_combinations(int[] a, int index, int n) {
    if (n > 0 && n < 10) {
      if (index == n) {
        if (is_ascending(a, n)) {
          System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, n)));
          System.out.print(", ");
        }
      } else {
        while (a[index] <= 9 - n + index + 1) {
          print_combinations(a, index + 1, n);
          if (index < n - 1 && a[index + 1] == 9 - n + index + 3) {
            a[index + 1] = 0;
          }
          a[index]++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

There are more elegant ways to achieve the desired output, but at least this shows you where your code had issues.

Here is a version that does not allocate 10 array entries, but first defines `n` and then uses that for a dynamic length for the array. Also, the iteration over the different digits can be done with a `for` loop, and you can also add logic to not start each time at 0, but at one more than the digit at the left. This way you don't need the check whether the array is ascending, as it is then guaranteed.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 3;
        int[] a = new int[n];
        print_combinations(a, 0, n);
    }

    static void print_combinations(int[] a, int index, int n) {
        if (index == n) {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a));
            System.out.print(", ");
        } else {
            int first = index > 0 ? a[index - 1] + 1 : 0;
            int last = 10 - n + index;
            for (int digit = first; digit <= last; digit++) {
                a[index] = digit;
                print_combinations(a, index + 1, n);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

print_combinations is being called recursively by itself hundreds of thousands of times until it overflows.

```
a[index]++;
```

is never reached in print_combinations due to index constantly being reset to 0 after the !has_ended check.

This means that all but the print_combinations call in the while loop are unreachable.

My personal recommendation is to just increment an integer like the example below and just use a bit of funky programming to check the ascending bit, just modifying your code to make it work but there are probably better ways.

```
public class TestCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 0;
        int n = 4;
        TestCode test = new TestCode();
        while(Integer.toString(a).length() < n-1){
            a++;
    
        }
        while(Integer.toString(a).length() <= n){
            test.print_combinations(a, 0, n);
            a++;
        }
    }

    public void print_combinations(int a, int index, int n) {
        char[] print = new char[n];
        char[] test = Integer.toString(a).toCharArray();
        if(test.length < n && test.length >= n - 1){
            print = new char[test.length+1];
            for(int x = 0; x <= test.length; x++){
                if(x == 0){
                    print[x] = '0';
                }else{
                    print[x] = test[x-1];
                }
            }
            if(this.is_ascending(print, n)){
                System.out.println(new String(print));
            }
        }else if(this.is_ascending(test, n)){
            System.out.println(new String(test));
        }
    }

    public boolean is_ascending(char[] a, int n) {
      int ctr = 0;

      while (ctr < n - 1) {
        if (Character.getNumericValue(a[ctr]) >= Character.getNumericValue(a[ctr + 1])) {
      return false;
        }
        ctr++;
      }
      return true;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're absolutely hellbent on using arrays, do the exact opposite, check for descending and when you print it out use something like

```
System.out.println("" + a[index +2] + a[index +1] + a[index])
```

This will grab an array of [9,7,4] and print it out as "479"

Doing it this way will drastically ease your interactions with arrays and reduce the need for recursions since you're working from the front of the array and make troubleshooting far easier.